# How to change default background colour in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-router-flux, react-native-screens

I recently updated from RN 0.60 to 0.65, and after hours of debugging I can get my app to build and run again. However, for some reason the background colour of my app has changed from white to gray.

I'm using `react-native-router-flux` for navigation, but either the styling is broken in the latest react-native release, or I'm missing something obvious.

Here's how it has always been set up:

```
const RouterComponent = () => {
  const sceneConfig = {
    cardStyle: {
      backgroundColor: 'white',
    },
  };

  return (
    <Router {...sceneConfig}/>
    [...]
    </Router>
```

This no longer does anything. Here's what else I've tried:

- Directly adding style properties to `<Router>` using `sceneStyle`, as recommended in [the docs](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/docs/API.md)
- Directly adding style properties to each individual scene by using `style` property

Neither of these approaches work, and I'm now stuck with an app that has a gray background (#f2f2f2) on every screen. I'm not even sure if this is an issue with `react-native-router-flux` but it definitely seems like the most likely cause.

Digging through the issues on the Github repo, I found one person flagging that this could be an incompatibility with `react-native-screens`, which seems to have been added to my project as a result of the upgrade to RN 0.65. This is a shot in the dark, as I'm not even sure what that library is used for.

Has anyone managed to change the background colour of their app on RN 0.65 and `react-native-router-flux` v4.3.0?

Edit:

Here's an example of how I tried to style individual scenes, which didn't work:

```
          <Scene
            title={'Profile'}
            renderTitle={() => <View />}
            // Neither of the below options has any effect
            sceneStyle={{backgroundColor: 'red'}}
            style={{backgroundColor: 'red'}}
            key="profile"
            hideNavBar
            icon={TabIcon}
            iconName="account-circle-outline"
            back={false}
            component={Profile}
          />
```

Comment: can you add the related code "Directly adding style properties to each individual scene by using style property" ? It should work properly.

Comment: @nima Yes, I've updated the reply. I also tried using the `sceneStyle` property on the individual scene. Neither worked.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you create a wrapper component and wrap your pages on it to easily manage the specification.

this is the way I use it in my applications:

```
const MainView = ({children}) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>{children}</View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#ff0",
  },
});
```

Now, use this component in other screens, for example in the `HomeScreen`:

```
const HomeScreen = () => {
  // rest of the codes ...

  return (
    <MainView>
      // rest of the codes ...
    </MainView>
  )
}
```

You can even pass the container style through props to the `MainView` instead of creating the style on it. in this way, you can pass different styles in different screens.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I tried it and it works, but it feels like quite a hacky fix to the problem. This is particularly messy when I have conditional rendering, as I need to wrap each case in the <MainView> component. It works for now though, so thanks!

Comment: I use this way for all my screens, even in web applications with `react.js` it gives you some advantage in the feature. @owiewio